# Append to a list using indexes stored in another list

Tags: python, list

In line with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290768/access-element-in-list-using-indexes-stored-in-another-list), I'm looking for a way to append elements to a list where the index pointing to where in the list it should be appended is stored in another list.

Consider the list:

```
b = [[[[[0.2], [3]], [[4.5], [78]], [[1.3], [0.23]], [[6.], [9.15]]],
[[[3.1], [44]], [[1.], [66]], [[0.18], [2.3]], [[10], [7.5]]],
[[[3], [4.]], [[12.3], [12]], [[7.8], [3.7]], [[1.2], [2.1]]]]]
```

and the indexes stored in:

```
c = [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I need to use the indexes stored in `c` to append an element into that location in `b`.

This won't work:

```
b[c[0]][c[1]][c[2]][c[3]].append('new element')
```

because the shape of `b` changes with every run of my code and thus the number of elements in `c`. This is why I need a *general* way of using `c` to append the `new element` into `b`.

Something like:

```
b[*c].append('new element')
```

which of course doesn't work but gives an idea of what I'm after.

Comment: Shouldn't the last position of c be the position where to insert the element into the list, instead of appending it?

Comment: @tobias_k yes, thank you for bringing it to my attention. I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [`operator.getitem`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.getitem) and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to gradually step into the nested lists.

To insert the item into sublist `c[:-1]` at position `c[-1]`:

```
>>> reduce(operator.getitem, c[:-1], b).insert(c[-1], "new")
```

Or to append the item to sublist `c`:

```
>>> reduce(operator.getitem, c, b).append("new")
```

To retrieve the item at index `c`:

```
>>> reduce(operator.getitem, c, b)
'new'
```